# Change data type in table due to Disk Space/Memory Error

Tags: sql, database, ms-access

Attempts at changing data type in Access have failed due to error:

> "There isn't enough disk space or memory". Over 385,325 records exists in the table.

Attempts at the following links, among other StackOverFlow threads, have failed:
[Can't change data type on MS Access 2007](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2429052/cant-change-data-type-on-ms-access-2007)
[Microsoft Access can't change the datatype. There isn't enough disk space or memory](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/d3742777-565f-492a-add5-49462166d884/microsoft-access-cant-change-the-datatype-there-isnt-enough-disk-space-or-memory?forum=accessdev)

The intention is to change data type for one column from "Text" to "Number". The aforementioned links cannot accommodate that either due to size or the desired data type fields.

Breaking out the table may not be an option due to the number of records.

Help on this would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I cannot tell for sure about MS Access, but for MS SQL one can avoid a table rebuild (requiring lots of time and space) by appending a new column that allows null- values at the rightmost end of the table, update the column using normal update queries and AFAIK even drop the old column and rename the new one. So in the end it's just the location of that column that has changed.

As for your 385,325 records (I'd expect that number to be correct) even if the table had 1000 columns with 500 unicode- characters each we'd end up with approximately `385,325*1000*500*2 ~ 385 GB` of data. That should nowadays not be the maximum available - so:

- if it's the disk space you're running out of, how about move the data to some other computer, change the DB there and move it back.
- if the DB seems to be corrupted (and standard tools didn't help (**make a copy**)) it will most probably help to create a new table or database using table creation (better: create manually and append) queries.

Comment: Thanks, I've for now, did it manually by breaking up the table into 6 parts and appended each part via importing the data from excel. 6 spreadsheets.. At the end, all values are now changed from text to number, after setting the column to 'number' data type during each of the 6 imports.

Comment: Each import was at around 65,000 records to avoid reaching the maximum that excel can handle.

Comment: Point of interest: A single Access database file cannot exceed 2GB. Since an Access table cannot span files, the effective maximum size of an Access table is (slightly less than) 2GB.

Comment: Whatever works for you is valid, but excel is a beast on data and especially data- types. I'd prefer a table in the same DB or link another (temp)DB in to do the job - next time ;).